# make:No rule to make target install. Stop for openldap

Tags: linux, makefile, redhat

I Just unzip openldap in `/opt/openldap` directory and then trying to run following commands

```
make depend
make
make test
make install
```

but i am getting below exceptions check the added screen shot

[image]

**EDIT:-**

output of ./configure command

[image]

**EDIT1 :-**

```
 yum install gcc
```

also giving below exception

[image]

Comment: Did you run `./configure` first?

Comment: Its also giving exception please check edit question

Comment: It seems you don't have any compiler installed.

Comment: I tried to install  by this command 'yum install gcc' it also end with error please check screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# yum provides kernel-headers
kernel-headers-<version>-<release>.<arch>
# yum install kernel-headers
```

Now, that would have been done for you automatically if you had a YUM repository configured that held the kernel-headers RPM.

Is you system configured to use Red Hat RHN?  or Oracle ULN?  or some other repository?  Likely you are missing an essential channel such as "distribution media" or some such.